# Angularjs Web Api Multpli Post action

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller, web, asp.net-web-api

I am beginner in Angularjs  I want to have in my web api controller two post methods: one for registration and one for login. Here is my web api controller post methods:

```
   //[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
   // [ActionName("register")]
   // [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostRegister(Users Student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int card = rnd.Next(52);
            Student.user_id = card;
            // _usertManager.AddUser(Student);
            var activateToken = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(Student.user_mail, Student.password, Student);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Student);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = Student.user_id }));
            //  _mailManager.Sendmail("salah.rzzaz90@gmail.com", "salahsayedrzzaz@gmail.com","dd","dd");
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }

    ////[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    //[ActionName("Login")]
    //[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostLogin(string userMaill, string passwordd)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _usertManager.Login(userMaill, passwordd);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, userMaill);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { userMaill = userMaill }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

my angular service :

```
this.post = function (Users) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/api/HomeApi",
            data:Users 
        });
        return request;
    }

this.post = function (userMaill, passwordd) {
    var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/api/HomeApi",
        data: { userMaill: userMaill, passwordd: passwordd }
    });
    return request;
}`
```

my angular controller :

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var Users = {
        user_id: $scope.user_id,
        user_mail: $scope.user_mail,
        fullname: $scope.fullname,
        mobile: $scope.mobile,
        secondmail: $scope.secondmail,
        password: $scope.password,
        type: $scope.type
    };

        var promisePost = CRUD_OperService.post(Users);
        promisePost.then(function (pl) {
            $scope.user_id = pl.data.user_id;
            GetAllRecords();
            $scope.Message = "Student Updated Successfuly";
            ClearModels();
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Err" + err);
        });
};

$scope.login = function () {
    var userMaill = $scope.userMaill;
    var passwordd = $scope.passwordd;

    var promisePost = CRUD_OperService.put(userMaill, passwordd);
    promisePost.then(function (pl) {
        $scope.user_id = pl.data.user_id;
        GetAllRecords();
        $scope.Message = "done";
        ClearModels();
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err" + err);
    });
};
```

My problem is that when I click register and login scope it calls PostRegister.

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: My problem that when i click register and login scope it call PostRegister

Comment: You may need to alter the routing in your api config file, but it's not entirely clear...

Comment: Not sure if you copied and pasted incorrectly, but in your angular service, you are overwriting your .post method, the second time you assign a function to it. Is one of them supposed to be .put?

Comment: The standard convention for web api is to only have one of each type of verb per controller, so you would have a `RegisterController` and a `LoginController`. You don't HAVE to do it this way, but if you don't i think you are making it unnecessarily complex.

Comment: can you explain more , its not acceotable to make 2 post methods ?

Comment: can i call web api with action name not Controller ? if i should use put can anone provide me an example ?

Comment: Can i create Login Controller and Register Controller but i want to use one view because login and resigster in one page